# Fixed footer and short screen

Tags: css, layout, css-position

Do you have any suggestion how to make fixed positioned footer working on short screens/lower resolution?

I have footer:

```
#footer {position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%;  height: 35px; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); line-height: 35px; color: #fff; font-size: 14px; text-transform: uppercase}
```

which works fine on most resolutions, but when screen height is smaller then 900px, because its fixed it overlaps the content. How do you fix such issues? I was considering checking screen resolution with js, and then instead of fixed give it position: relative. What do you think?

Comment: @dease Check the Below Answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it really have to be fixed? Support is still a bit sloppy in a few browsers... if it was absolutely positioned you could add a padding to the main content so the footer never overlaps the content.

Anyway, what you are trying to do can be easily accomplished with css media queries. You can start here: http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Answer (score 0):

Give Z-index = 10;
(Some higher Z-index so that it will stand out)

Comment: But then it will stand out over content, what I want achieve is to detect short screen and  then move content below somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this
css :

```
html,body{position:relative; margin:0; padding:0; height:100%}

.footer{ position:fixed; height:30px; background-color:grey; width:100%; bottom:0px; z-index:999}
```